# Python Get parent class instance in decorator of method

Tags: python, function, class, decorator

If i have:

```
routes = RoutesNamespace('tests', description='Tests related stuff')

class test1(Resource):
    @routes.cache(100)
    def post(self):
        pass
```

how i can retreive a class instance of "test1" in decorator @routes.cache ?

```
class RoutesNamespace(Namespace):

    def cache(self, delay):
      test1 = class of test1 ?????
```

Comment: `routes.cache(100)` is applied to the function `post` before the class is defined, so there isn't even a class (let alone an instance of that class) that *could* be accessed by `routes.cache`.

Comment: Decorators affect how the attribute `post` is defined; they are not called every time the resulting method is called.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "in" when you say:

> how i can retreive a class instance of "test1" in decorator
> @routes.cache ?"

Recall that decorators are used for [transforming functions/methods](https://peps.python.org/pep-0318/#abstract). Decorator transformations involve wrapping a function within a new function, which then subsumes the name of the original function. Hence - and bear with me for a moment - we need to distinguish between two steps, which I'll call the "define" step and the "call" step.

In the "define" step, the function is prepared (hand wave here, all the usual decorator wrapping goings-on) and assigned its name; in the "call" step, the function is passed its arguments (aka "scope").

Recall also that "finding the class instance" means "having access to `self`". And since `self` is an argument, it is only available at call-time. (For more context about decorators and scope, you should totally read up on closures. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) even has some examples written in Python.)

So: if what you mean by "in [my] decorator" is "when my decorated `post` function is *called*", no problem, here you go:

```
>>> class RoutesNamespace(Namespace):
...     def cache(self, delay):
...         def wraps(f):
...             print("I AM BEING DEFINED")
...             def wrapper(self, *a, **kw):
...                 print("I AM BEING CALLED")
...                 print("instance:", self)
...                 print("class:", self.__class__)
...                 return f(self, *a, **kw)
...             return wrapper
...         return wraps
...
>>>
>>> routes = RoutesNamespace()
>>>
>>>
>>> class test1(Resource):
...     @routes.cache(100)
...     def post(self):
...         pass
...
I AM BEING DEFINED
```

Let's try to call it now:

```
>>> t = test1()
>>> t.post()
I AM BEING CALLED
instance: <__main__.test1 object at 0x7fe8d818d400>
class: <class '__main__.test1'>
```

(Note I'm printing out both the instance and class here. Your question asks for the "class instance", which is represented by `self`, but your pseudocode asks for the class (`test1 = class of test1 ?????`). Not sure which is a typo so including both. NB from an instance you can retrieve the class with `self.__class__`.)

If, on the other hand, what you mean by "in" is "when my decorator wraps the `post` function", then unfortunately what you're asking for isn't possible because the "wrap" happens during the "define" step, but the scope you need (`self`) is not available until the "call" step. (Hopefully the all-cap "I AM BEING :step:" above help make this clear.) In other words: `self` is only available when an instance of `test1` is created and its `post` method is called, but that of course cannot happen until `post` is done being defined.